# autocomplete using angularjs (not able to get input value)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-ngmodel

I have the following plunker attached herewith
http://plnkr.co/edit/NPpjRM54vPu56GH9N1kI?p=preview

As you can see, there is a list of available tags. If i write 'a' in the input field, several autocomplete items show up below.

If i keep typing, i can see what i have typed beside it using the below code

```
<input id="tags" ng-keyup="complete()" ng-model="data" /> selected = {{data}}
```

But instead of typing, i just select 'ActionScript' in its dropdown from autocomplete, it doesnot get updated to ng-model.

Can someone let me know how to select from the dropdown and have it updated to the ng-model as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Autocomplete docs, there's an "select" event that will do what you need:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: $scope.availableTags,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $scope.data = ui.item.value;
  }
});
```

This will make the value of $scope.data to change after you focus out of the field. If you want to propagate the change immediately, you can use a 0 second $timeout, like so:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: $scope.availableTags,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $timeout(function() { $scope.data = ui.item.value; }, 0);
  }
});
```

Keep in mind that you need to inject $timeout in your controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope, $timeout){ ... });
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/3rstgrTQJp5voYEJdo2C?p=preview